# Не могу поменять иконку в actionbar в SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbar, android-search-view

Пытаюсь поменять иконку на свою у `SaerchView`, но по не понятной мне причине иконка не меняется.

Вот мой `toolbar_menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="@android:string/search_go"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_sort"
        android:title="@string/action_sort"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Вот так я пытаюсь поменять иконку:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_toolbar_menu, menu);

    toolbarSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.toolbar_action_search).getActionView();


    ImageView searchButtonIcon = (ImageView) toolbarSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button);
    searchButtonIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search);


    return true;
}
```

Я понимаю, что я могу просто в XML поменять `android:icon`. Но мне в основном проекте нужно менять иконку программно и выше приведен всего лишь пример, чтобы описать проблему.

По какой причине смена иконки может игнорироваться?

Comment: если реч идет о вот этой иконке http://take.ms/qbFI1
то так `menu.findItem().setIcon()`

Comment: Да иконку удалось поменять. К сожалению не могу выбрать ваш ответ как правильный.